# POM.xml error fix

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

I am very new to eclipse and maven repository. I got a project to config the errors of POM.xml. I fixed many of it, but I am unable to fix some. Following are that errors.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>jlibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jlibs-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgodies.form</groupId>
        <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
```

In Maven repository folder there are not all the files which are in the other folders, so I put them manually, but still no results.

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: missing artifact in all above dependencies. I dont know how to fix it.Please advice.

Comment: Make sure the directory structure of the artifact locations is correct.  For example, for `com.jgodies.form`, the directory structure should be `com` -> `jgodies` -> `form`, then within `form`, place the artifact with the correct version number, e.g. `forms-2.3.jar`.

Comment: C:\Users\nimesh\.m2\repository\com\jgodies\form\forms\2.3

that is my path.. so I assume the dependency path is correct, Am I?

Comment: The error message has not been included in this question, and now it is 18 months old it looks like it has been abandoned. Voting to put on hold as incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

All the Oracle realted jars are not the part of the Central Maven Repository.
May be the case with the other oracle related jars. That is the reason why its not able to resolve the dependencies.

You should create a separate custom repository on your company server where you can put all these jar and configure that in POM.xml. Maven will first check the Central reposiroty and if it does not find the files will later check the custom repositry.

For locally running Maven you will have to do a MVN Install manually. you should never manuallly copy any jars to the m2 repositiry

Answer (score 0):

Getting the JDBC drivers is a bit tricky. Please check [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/) for directions.

> Due to Oracle license restriction, there is NO public Maven repository provides Oracle JDBC  driver. To use Oracle jdbc drive with Maven, you have to install it manually into your Maven  local repository.